# Do I need a left, natural or simple join in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, marketplace

I am new to PHP coding and just trying to fix some functionality on my site that was left over from the lead developer.

The site, [[Vloggi]](http://vloggi.com), is a marketplace. So I need to show the name of the job poster in the [assignments page](http://vloggi.com/commission) . The table I have the jobs in only has the ID, not the name.

So I need a join, but I've tried and it breaks the entire site.

The SQL has 17 tables, I need to display the User Name (usr_name) contained in table 3, the organisation contained in table 7 (usrg_orgname) with the job posting user (vlop_usr_id) details in table 14.

The primary key is users.usr_id, which is linked to users_gor.usrg_usr_id and vlog-ops.vlog_usr_id.

Table 3: `users`
usr_id, usr_email,  usr_password,   usr_fbuser, usr_fbtoken,    **usr_name**,   usr_loc_name,   usr_loc_lat1,   usr_loc_lon1,   usr_loc_lat2,   usr_loc_lon2,   usr_status, usr_gor,    usr_vgr,    usr_token,  usr_regtoken,

table 7: `users_gor`
usrg_usr_id, usrg_creditops, usrg_creditvlog, usrg_creditvlogette, usrg_destination, **usrg_orgname**, usrg_orgtype, usrg_location, usrg_website, usrg_jobtitle, usrg_phone, usrg_address1, usrg_address2, usrg_state, usrg_postcode, usrg_country

Table 14: `vlog-ops`
vlop_id, vlop_title, vlop_description, vlop_tags, vlop_deadline, vlop_quantity, vlop_quantityposted, vlop_vser_id, **vlop_usr_id**,vlop_loc_name, vlop_loc_lat1, vlop_loc_lon1, vlop_loc_lat2, vlop_loc_lon2, vlop_campaign, vlop_rules, vlop_tips, vlop_status

So in main.php i have written the following Sql lookup
in main.php, I have the following SQL lookups:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_gor WHERE usrg_usr_id = ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$rows = $db->select($sql);
$users_gor = $rows[0];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_vgr WHERE usrv_usr_id = ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$rows = $db->select($sql);
$users_vgr = $rows[0];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usr_id = ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$rows = $db->select($sql);
$users = $rows[0];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM vlog-ops WHERE vlop_usr_id ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$rows = $db->select($sql);
$users = $rows[0];

$sql = "SELECT usr_name AS vlop_usr_name FROM users WHERE usr_id = ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$rows = $db->select($sql);
$users = $rows[0];
```

And then in the page template itself, I have written

```
<?php echo $vlop['vlop_vser_id'] ?>
<?php echo $vlop['vlop_usr_name'] ?>
```

The first one works, the second doesn’t. What I want eventually is to display the user name and the organisation name in a table.

Whenever I try a JOIN or a NATURAL JOIN or a LEFT JOIN it breaks and the entire site goes blank.

Any help for a newbie would be appreciated with a million thanks.

Comment: What does your code look like when you try a JOIN? It does look like a somewhat classic JOIN scenario to me...

Comment: post your join code and also explain exactly in what way it breaks.

Comment: Thanks  @Alan 

The JOIN I used was as follows
    $sql = “SELECT usr_name FROM users
NATURAL JOIN vlog-ops  WHERE usr_id = ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])


When I added to main.php, the whole site went white.

Should I have added it directly to the page instead of the echo?

Comment: And thanks @PauloHgo

Comment: You must also validate what it's returning because you are assuming that always there are result and maybe it's returning nothing and your accessing to position 0

Comment: Try to add tables structure screen shot image to allow more and easier understand about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you use JOIN you need to specify how you're joining them. 
In the query below I'm assuming you're looking for the fields in bold from your question.

```
$query='SELECT u.usr_name, g.usrg_orgname, v.vlop_usr_id  FROM users u 
JOIN vlog-ops v on u.usr_id = v.vlop_usr_id 
JOIN users_gor g on u.usr_id = g.usrg_usr_id';
```

I believe I got the name of the fields right but if not just replace them with the correct ones.

Once you have the data fetched, you just loop through the results:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo 'User name = ' . $row['u.usr_name'];
    echo 'Org name = ' . $row['g.usrg_orgname'];
    echo 'Job posting user id = ' . $row['v.vlop_usr_id'];
}
```

Comment: I think it always better to explicitly state the type of join - it makes your intent clearer to the reader. So INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN OR CROSS JOIN. There are few cases in practice where I would ever use a NATURAL JOIN to implicitly use the relationship - better to spell out the join conditions as Paulo has done.

Comment: Thanks. I tried inserting that code into the controller page and again, the whole site when white,

Comment: $sql = "SELECT u.usr_name, g.usrg_orgname, v.vlop_usr_id  FROM users u 
 JOIN vlog-ops v on u.usr_id = v.vlop_usr_id 
 JOIN users_gor g on u.usr_id = g.usrg_usr_id;

Comment: Did you try running that query in MySql Workbench or directly in the client? What's the result of the query itself outside of your PHP code?

Comment: Hi @PauloHgo  PHPMyAdmin says it's a ER_PARSE_ERROR

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-ops v on u.usr_id = v.vlop_usr_id 
JOIN users_gor g on u.usr_id = g.usrg_usr_i' at line 2

Comment: It was the hyphen. Once I enclosed vlog-ops inside back ticks, it worked. So how do I now echo that in the php? Sorry, if it's obvious!

Comment: @JustinWastnage I edited the answer with some basic code that loops through the results of the query, as long as your query works now.

Comment: @PauloHgo  Thanks. I'm completely lost now. Whenever I post the code into the controller template (main.php), the entire site goes white.
So I tried doing it locally on the commission.php page and ditto. Maybe there is conflicting code somewhere else in the page?

Comment: So I tried using both the query and echo together on the actual page and it doesn't break the site, but doesn't display either Look at the bottom item, Client name in this entry [link](https://vloggi.com/commission/20)

Comment: @Alan: would be worth examining why your tables are ill suited to `NATURAL JOIN`. First suspect would be tables with too many columns. The most common design flaw here in my experience is failing to differentiate between 'entity' tables and 'relationship' tables (those that map relationships between 'entities'). Most folk get it when the relationship in question has 'many' in it but fail to move 'from one to one' relationships to their own tables. Suggest you start here.