# How to fetch and echo the results of a JOIN in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, echo

A re-post of a question posted here a [few weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502466/do-i-need-a-left-natural-or-simple-join-in-sql), that I'm still struggling with.

So all I want to do is display the username of the person who has created an assignment to be displayed on pages like this: https://vloggi.com/commission/21

At present in the controller page I have the following queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_gor WHERE usrg_usr_id = ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$rows = $db->select($sql);
$users_gor = $rows[0];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_vgr WHERE usrv_usr_id = ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$rows = $db->select($sql);
$users_vgr = $rows[0];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usr_id = ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$rows = $db->select($sql);
$users = $rows[0];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM vlog-ops WHERE vlop_usr_id ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$rows = $db->select($sql);
$users = $rows[0];

$sql = "SELECT usr_name AS vlop_usr_name FROM users WHERE usr_id = ".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);        
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


$sql = "SELECT usr_name  FROM users WHERE usr_id='".$db->quote($user_info['usr_id'])." LIMIT 1";
$creator = $db->select1($sql);
$users = $rows[0];

$query = "SELECT u.usr_name, g.usrg_orgname, v.vlop_usr_id  FROM users u 
JOIN vlog-ops v on u.usr_id = v.vlop_usr_id 
JOIN users_gor g on u.usr_id = g.usrg_usr_id";
```

And then in the template page, I have the following fetch and echo.

```
             <?php
             $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 echo 'User name = ' . $row['u.usr_name'];
                 echo 'Org name = ' . $row['g.usrg_orgname'];
                 echo 'Job posting user id = ' . $row['v.vlop_usr_id'];
             }
             ?>
```

But it doesn't work. I tried Paulo Hgo's code and it doesn't work either.

So I understand the basic concept of JOIN, but need some help actually echoing or printing the variable.

Sorry for re-posting.

Comment: are you asking a SQL question or PHP? Are the SQL queries returning any results?

Answer (score 0):

First of, you are retrieving the column incorrectly, the resulting associated array doesn't include any dots (.) for fields like u.usr_name or u.anyfields, it will return the actual table fields. To check the row from associated array you can print it like below (just for the sake of looking at the structure or array keys generated)

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($row);
      echo '</pre>';
      die(); //just return 1 iteration.
    }
 ?>
```

the output of this is something like below:

```
Array
(
    [usr_name] => john
    [usrg_orgname] => doe
    ...
)
```

Then you can refer to its fields/key directly. Use field alias if you have fields with the same name in each table.

Fix your above code by using the actual field names, please see below:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if($result) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo 'User name = ' . $row['usr_name'];
     echo 'Org name = ' . $row['usrg_orgname'];
     echo 'Job posting user id = ' . $row['vlop_usr_id'];
   }
} else {
   echo 'Something went wrong.'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, @imprezzeb. Thanks, but I'm not really quite sure where I add that code. In the query or in the echo. Sorry is that's obvious.

Comment: @JustinWastnage, my above code was just for your reference, you can add it inside while loop, but to fix your code you need to remove "u." in u.usr_name, just use the actual field name in this case usr_name.

Comment: Hi @imprezzeb. It's still not working. I have gone over and over. When I insert the echo code into the template page nothing works and when I insert the entire code into the main page, the entire site goes blank. I can get the code to work in SQL.

Comment: Please add a result check like above. This is to check if indeed your sql query returns results.